# javascript to move image across page when someone clicks a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a strange request from a client that has an image move across the page from left to right of the whole width of the screen when someone clicks on a link... I'm not a javascript expert, but I was hoping someone could please steer me in the right direction on how this could be done?

Thanks! Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: A possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021779/moving-an-image-from-a-to-b-with-javascript).

Comment: hmm thanks for the reply, that issue is soooo similar to what I need.  My image is even a van ha, but I just don't know how they actually implement that code.  the jquery annimate feature sounds like it should work but I just don't know how to set everything up.... lil help? Sorry

Comment: Can you show me the code you currently have? What have you tried? Stick it in a fiddle and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I'm getting so close!  I just need to figure out a way to slow down the animation... I'm kinda a jquery noob so maybe it's easier than how I've done it?  Here's the js fiddle... feel free to update http://jsfiddle.net/CDRk5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `jQuery` animate function.  You could animate changing the position of the image in question.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thanks hmm yeah that seems appealing but I don't see any examples that really do what I need or do I know how to set it up